# How to generate json with c++ and boost library

Tags: c++, json, boost

I want to generate json in following format and i have written code as follows as i am beginer in c++ so i want to do it in more efficient way same operation.

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "cake",
    "ppu": "0.55",
    "option":
    {
        "options":
        [
            {
                "id": "5001",
                "type": "furniture"
            },
            {
                "id": "5002",
                "type": "furniture2"
            },
            {
                "id": "5003",
                "type": "furniture3"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Grid":
    [
        {
            "id": "5001",
            "type": "furniture"
        },
        {
            "id": "5002",
            "type": "furniture2"
        },
        {
            "id": "5003",
            "type": "furniture3"
        },
        {
            "id": "5004",
            "type": "furniture4"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i have following code for json generated

```
generateJson(){
boost::property_tree::ptree members,members1,child,child1,child2,child3,children,options,option;
anotherStructName c;
   members.put<string>("id","0001");
   members.put<string>("type","donut");
   members.put<string>("name","cake");
   members.put<double>("ppu",0.55);
   children.push_back(std::make_pair("",child));
   children.push_back(std::make_pair("",child1));
   children.push_back(std::make_pair("",child2));
   children.push_back(std::make_pair("",child3));
   option.push_back(std::make_pair("",child));
   option.push_back(std::make_pair("",child1));
   option.push_back(std::make_pair("",child2));
   options.put_child("option",batter);
   members.put_child("options",options);
   members.add_child("Grid",children);
 return c.createJsonString(members);
}
```

//now logic for create json

```
string anotherStructName::createJsonString(boost::property_tree::ptree json)
{
    std::stringstream jsonString;
    write_json(jsonString, json);
    return jsonString.str();
}
```

//above code is working fine but i want to add it through loop with using vector and data adding dynamically in "id" and "type" field of option array.

Answer (score 2):

if you have "id", "type" datas as vectors you can generate "options" part of your json  like this

```
vector<string> id, type;
boost::property_tree::ptree options, option;

for (int i = 0; i < id.size() && i < type.size(); ++i) {
    boost::property_tree::ptree child;

    child.put<string>("id",id[i]);
    child.put<string>("type",type[i]);
    options.push_back(std::make_pair("",child));
}

option.put_child("options",options);
```

Comment: ,I want to take id and type in structure.

Comment: what is your structure?

Comment: ``` struct Data{ int id;string name; }; vector<Data> data``` like this one.

Comment: child.put<int>("id",data[i].id); child.put<string>("type",data[i].name);

Comment: It is returing empty,how can i insert value of id and type,because i am here specifying only data[i].id and data[i].name.